# Flex DataGrid rows not rendered at all

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, air, rendering

My application uses numerous DataGrids. I have one pop-up with a DataGrid where, currently about 50% of the time, when the pop-up is first raised the DataGrid rows are blank - nothing is drawn, not even the grid lines (see the attached screenshot). The header is drawn correctly, and the scrollbar is drawn to show all the data items are there, but when the scrollbar is clicked I get an exception from the animation interpolator. Other than that, I don't get any errors or exceptions, just no rendered items. There are no custom item renderers, but one column has a TextInput grid item editor.

Has anyone seen anything like this? Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I should start looking? As I mentioned, usually the pop-up displays correctly (and all my other DataGrids are fine), so there's nothing obviously broken in my code.

I should add that I only see this problem on Windows (XP SP3). When I run my app on OS X, I don't see the problem occurring. I'm using Flash Builder 4.7 and the latest AIR SDK (although my code is a couple of years old now and not exactly "bleeding edge").

Cheers,

John :^P
[image: Screenshot showing non-rendered rows]

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: When I click on the vertical scrollbar I get `Error: Interpolator cannot calculate interpolated values when startValue (NaN) or endValue (NaN) is not a number. at spark.effects.interpolation::NumberInterpolator/interpolate()`. The rest of the stack trace is in the `spark.effects.animation::Animation` class. I don't get any exceptions when I click on the main `DataGrid` row area.

Comment: Show some code on where you're using animations in this popup.

Comment: I'm not using animations in this pop-up. My code is just boring data-bound controls. The animation is something internal to the DataGrid.

Comment: Enough code to make a reproducible case would be important here.  A full stack trace may help.  Are you using the MX DataGrid or the Spark DataGrid?

Comment: I'm using the Spark DataGrid. In the end further refactoring has revealed and removed the problem: the pop-up's `close()` was getting called before the DataGrid had finished constructing itself, and this managed to break it. So the fix is "Don't do that, then." Thanks for your interest in my question.